# WebClient DownloadString not getting all the information

Tags: c#, webclient, downloadstring

I'm trying to do the following:

```
string url = @"https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/bladibla?thumbsize=206c";
WebClient myClient = new WebClient();
string picasaxml = myClient.DownloadString(url);
```

When I go to the url (which is not the real url ofcourse, the "bladibla" is not the actual username), I get to see all the information.
When I look at the picasaxml, I'm missing parts of the information. Some xml-sections are missing in the document.

Can anyone help me?

-- Update --
The real url is : https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/tim@boerenbond.be?thumbsize=206c
so if you go to that url, you should get a lot of information, including the names of some photoalbums that were created there.
But when I run the code as displayed higher, i'm not getting all that information.

Ok, I just noticed that when I go to the page on another machine, I'm not getting all the info either.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that the problem is with `WebClient` itself. My guess is that either you're either misdiagnosing it (we don't know how you're examining the string) or that the server responds differently to different user agents, or your browser is passing authentication information that your `WebClient` is not. Without more information, unfortunately we're unlikely to be able to help.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex It seems that would be the case, since I have the same result on a pc where I didn't go to the page befores. But even when I pass NetworkCredentials, I'm still not getting all the data.